# Cassandra cql version using binary protocol

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface, cql3

In my command line showConnected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
 version but cql3 binary protocol host is different what should i do instead of using thrift to binary protocol in cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the port, the binary protocol uses port 9042. Search for `native_transport_port` in your `cassandra.yaml` file. The host should be the same.